# JavaScript JSON parse error: single-quotes... where?

Tags: javascript, json

I was using a upload php script with AS3 and now with JavaScript. There is a test feature that returns this if it's ok:

```
{"erro":"OK","msg":"","descr":"op:ini,urlArq:\/Library\/WebServer\/Documents\/www\/sintran\/fotos\/teste.log"}
```

But JavaScript is returning error: JSON Parse error: Single quotes (') are not allowed in JSON

As you can see, there is no single quotes. Maybe the "descr" property is confusing the parse engine with : and , but do not wish to change it so AS3 will not read this property anymore (is useful data).

Any ideas?

Edit: slashes are escaped with backslashes, but is not displaying above.

Edit: The code:

```
formUpload.prototype.ini_test = function(evt){
    console.log("ini_test - Retorno do servidor: "+evt.target.responseText);
    var jsonRes = evt.target.responseText;
    jsonRes = jsonRes.slice(jsonRes.indexOf("{"), jsonRes.lastIndexOf("}")+1);
    try{
        var Res = JSON.parse(jsonRes);
        if(Res.erro!="OK"){
            this.monitor_ini.innerHTML = "Erro: "+Res.msg;
        } else {
            this.monitor_ini.innerHTML = "";
            var jExts = this.form.arquivo_tipos.value;
            this.Exts = JSON.parse(jExts);
            this.monitor_info.innerHTML = this.ajuda();
        }
    } catch(e){
        this.monitor_ini.innerHTML = "Erro!";
        console.log("formUpload ini_test Erro: "+e.message+" Resposta do servidor: "+jsonRes);
        alert("Erro de teste de Upload. Resposta JavaScript: "+e.message);
    }
}
```

Edit: all shown by console log - but I try without escaping slashes this time, so the final string is different:

```
ini_test - Retorno do servidor: {"erro":"OK","msg":"","descr":"op:ini,urlArq:\/Library\/WebServer\/Documents\/www\/sintran\/fotos\/teste.log"}
formUpload ini_test Erro: JSON Parse error: Single quotes (') are not allowed in JSON Resposta do servidor: {"erro":"OK","msg":"","descr":"op:ini,urlArq:/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/sintran/fotos/teste.log"}
```

Comment: How does the JavaScript code look like? Are you sure that exactly this string is given to `JSON.parse`, did you log it?

Comment: It's already JavaScript object. Why you trying to parse it?

Comment: @Givi: Why do you say that? What makes you think OP is trying to parse a JavaScript object.

Comment: @cookiemonster code that OP provided isn't a string it's object.

Comment: share your code... where you are getting the error...Your json is validate..[JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Which browser you are using..?

Comment: @Givi: No, what OP provided is some text. The context of how that text is used determines what kind of data was created. Could be JSON data (Unicode data in a specific format). It could be in a JavaScript program, being used to create a JavaScript object. It could be in a Go program, used to create a map value. Syntax and data are not the same thing. Different technologies frequently use the same syntax for different purposes.

Comment: @Gustavo: Why are you having to search the text for `{` and `}` characters? What does your `console.log()` give you?

Comment: The code is above, but is not a mystery, I'm just taking the json string and trying to parse it into an object.

Comment: @GustavoPinent: Yes, your intent is clear. Some people just don't understand what JSON is. The mystery is the error.

Comment: My server test is set to display most of error messages, so I got to search for the JSON string inside php and apache messages. In this case, there isn't, the log shows only what I copy into here.

Comment: Well that's just odd. Could you please show the entire text of your first `console.log()`, including the `ini_test - Retorno do servidor: ` part?

Comment: Are you sure it's not coming from here? `this.Exts = JSON.parse(jExts);`

Comment: Why this happens to me??? The bug was so close, if it was poisonous, I'd be dead. Thank you so much! Maybe you should publish the right answer, people will not read all this to find the answer - if you think this is constructive.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `.responseText` is valid JSON, most likely the error is coming from here:

```
var jExts = this.form.arquivo_tipos.value;
this.Exts = JSON.parse(jExts);
```

Whatever `.value` is coming from the form input must not be valid JSON, and is therefore throwing the error.

Since they're in the same `try/catch`, it's difficult to tell which one it is. If you need a `try/catch`, separate ones may be better.

Comment: I add the jExts in console.log, however I agree that is a bad practice using two operations in the same try/catch. I'll change this (later), also will try to implement event dispatching to deal better with errors.